# Rails common method for updating a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I am new to rails and I have a task to write a common method that will update a specific database field with a given value. And I should be able to invoke the method from anywhere in the app.**(I understand about the security flaw and so on.. But I was asked to do it anyway)** In my application controller I tried

```
  def update_my_model_status(model,id,field, value)
    @model = model.find(id)
    @model.update(field: value)
  end
```

Of course this doesn't work.. How to achieve this? What is the right way to do this? And if it is possible how to pass a model as an argument to a method?

Comment: I would advise against this method of updating your models. [security...security..blah blah]. What is the error you're getting, though?

Comment: @manu29.d dumb eyy ? My boss asked to do this.. Can't help it

Comment: @TonyVincent Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @TonyVincent Also it is clear if you update the codebase from which you call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails, why not use Rails?

Compare [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all):

`MyModel.where(id: 1).update_all(banned: true)`

or maybe [update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute):

`my_model.update_attribute(:banned, true)`

to:

`update_my_model_status(MyModel, 1, :banned, true)`

Notice how, despite being shorter, the first two approaches are significantly more expressive than the last - it is much more obvious what is happening. Not only that, but they are immediately more familiar to any Rails developer off the street, while the custom one has a learning curve. This, combined with the added code from the unnecessary method adds to the maintenance cost of the application. Additionally, the Rails methods are well tested and documented - are you planning to write that, too? Finally, the Rails methods are better thought out - for example, your prototype naively uses attribute validations, but does not check them (which could result in unexpected behavior) and makes more SQL queries than it needs to. It's fine to write custom methods, but let's not write arbitrary wrappers around perfectly fine Rails methods...

Comment: This is a terrible question, but I just couldn't help myself. It seems like we are missing information. It is hard to imagine what might motivate this desire in the workplace, it seems better suited to an academic exercise than something to put into production code. If this really is a request from your boss, you may want to consider looking for alternate employment - this app is almost certainly going to be an unmaintainable disaster.

Comment: We have say event, task, todo models. I need to update event status while todo is being updated. I hv been told that there will be so many unrelated models in the future that might require the same functionality (even i didn't understand the point and tried to raise my concern.. bt no use) and so write a custom common method. I am trying to learn here and ur answer helped thank u

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  def update_my_model_status(model,id,field, value)
    @model_var = model.capitalize.constantize.find(id)
    @model_var.update_attributes(field: value)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using `update` you should use `update_attributes`:

```
 def update_my_model_status(model,id,field, value)
    @model_var = model.find(id)
    @model.update_attributes(field: value)
  end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update

Comment: update_attributes will not run any validations on the model. And its not about which method I should use, its about the right way making it accessible throughout the app and passing a model as an argument